# iPad UIPopover presented over UIBarButtomItem covers BarButtomItem?

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I have UIBarButtomItem that shows popover when pressed:

```
//add help button
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Help", @"Help") style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(showInfoBubble:)] autorelease];
infoBubblePopOverVisible = NO;
self.infoBubblePopOverController = nil;
```

Here is show info bubble:

```
- (void) showInfoBubble: (id) sender {
[self dismissPopoverControllerExplicitly];
    
if (self.infoBubblePopOverController == nil) {
    InfoBubbleViewController *controller = [[InfoBubbleViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoBubbleViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    self.infoBubblePopOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navigationController];
    [controller release];
    [navigationController release];
}

//present popOverController
[self.infoBubblePopOverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
infoBubblePopOverVisible = YES;
```

}

But when presented popover is presented partially covering barbuttomitem:

[image]

How can i fix this?

Comment: what size is the popover? Perhaps there's not enough space to fit the controller on the screen so it is moved some pixels as compromise.

Comment: its 50x50, there is plenty of room